# How can I get lib ldap-client in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I can't get `lib ldap-client` in Node.js.

I used this page https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp to help solve the problem.

I installed `python`, `node-gyp`, `Visual Studio 2015`.

All of the packages for LDAP connection have this problem.

I'm working in Windows 7.

Here's my `package.json`:

```
   {
      "name": "taakapis",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "private": true,
      "main": "app.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/www"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "latest",
        "cookie-parser": "latest",
        "debug": "latest",
        "express": "latest",
        "jade": "latest",
        "morgan": "latest",
        "serve-favicon": "latest",
        "nodemon":"latest",
        "mysql":"latest",
        "date-and-time":"latest",
        "trim":"latest",
        "dateformat":"latest",
        "is-my-json-valid":"latest",
        "md5":"latest",
        "ldap-client":"latest"


      }
    }
```

Attempting to resolve package `ldap-client` I get this:

[image]

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if your gcc version configuration is not right. So try 
exporting the path.

`export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin:$PATH`